# Dart : How to get second to last item in a List

Tags: dart

I would like to get the second to last item in a `List`, similarly than with getter `last`.

I tried the following :

```dart
final list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

final secondToLast = (list..removeLast()).last; // Mutates the List
```

However it mutates the `List`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is many options available (however you should make sure that list is not null and has at least 2 elements) :

```dart
final list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// Works only for Lists
final secondToLast = list[list.length - 2];
final secondToLast = list.reversed.elementAt(1);
final secondToLast = list.reversed.skip(1).first;

// Works for any Iterable
final secondToLast = list.elementAt(list.length - 2);
```

To get something similar to `last`, you can write an extension on `Iterable` :

```dart
extension CustomIterable<T> on Iterable<T> {
  T? get secondToLast {
    return this == null || length < 2 ? null : elementAt(length - 2);
  }
}
```